# SQL get data between the last four weeks

Tags: sql, date, dbeaver

I would like to get data of the last four weeks. Now, I usually run the query on a Tuesday, therefore I have this code:

```
AND datatime between dateadd(day,-30,getdate()) and dateadd(day,-2,getdate())
```

I would like to run the query whenever I want (not just on Tuesday), but obtaining also the data from the same period (last four weeks from Monday to Sunday).

I have tried to do the following

```
AND datatime between dateadd(week,-4,getdate()) and dateadd(week,-1,getdate())
```

but it does not work, as the data obtained is not from the previous weeks (Monday to Sunday) but from the 7 days before the date in which I run it.

Any ideas on how to get the data, using that structure, so that I get data from the 4 previous weeks (Monday to Sunday) no matter when I run the query?

P.S I am using DBeaver.
Thank you.

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. That query is product specific.

Comment: i am using DBeaver

Answer (score 0):

If you want all data from the first monday in the last 4 weeks to today, you can use this :

```
AND datatime >= DATE_ADD(
         DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL - WEEKDAY(CURDATE()) DAY),
         INTERVAL - 4 WEEK)
```

But, if you want all the data from the first monday of the last 4 weeks to the last sunday, you can use this :

```
AND datatime >= DATE_ADD(
         DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL - WEEKDAY(CURDATE()) DAY),
         INTERVAL - 4 WEEK)
AND datatime < DATE_SUB(
         DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(NOW())-2 DAY)
```

**What's happening :**

You can find [Date and Time Functions Here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html). In this query, we are using:

1. **DATE_ADD(start, Interval) :** Add time values (Interval) to a date value  (start),
2. **DATE_SUB(end, Interval) :** Subtract a time value (Interval) from a date (end),
3. **CURDATE() :** Returns the current date,
4. **WEEKDAY(date) :** Returns the weekday index for date (0 = Monday, 1 = Tuesday, … 6 = Sunday),
5. **DAYOFWEEK(date) :** Returns the weekday index for date (1 = Sunday, 2 = Monday, …, 7 = Saturday)

So :

```
DATE_ADD(
      DATE_ADD(----------------------------------------------------------
             CURDATE(),                                                 |
             INTERVAL - WEEKDAY(CURDATE()) DAY //<== Return Today Index |-> Will Return the date of this week's monday : (25-01-2018 - 3 DAY) = 22-01-2018
                                               (WEEKDAY(25-01-2018) = 3)|
      ),-----------------------------------------------------------------
      INTERVAL - 4 WEEK //<== Will go 4 weeks back and start from monday
)
```

A working case [**Scenario**](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9QBLn2pxZeyK3oE59appVz/0).

Comment: Is there a mistake there? I dont understans the syntax of "WEEKDAY(CURDATE()) DAY)"

Comment: @Pabs88, hey, sorry for this late action! I've edited the answer, hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you, but it says "Invalid operation: syntax error at or near "DAY". Any ideas?